Pillar removal question
We are just a few inches short for a piece of furniture to maximize the space. Just wanted to know if I can remove or even cut it a few inches?
Inside photo:

Outside photo:


Better to cut the new piece of furniture. Otherwise the process looks like:
Remove or reduce pillar. Furniture fits. House falls on it. Were you in the house at the time? Too bad.
Pillars for no reason are not really a thing in building construction. Moving or removing one requires paying a civil or structural engineer (licensed to practice in your area) to determine if there's a way to remove it, and if there is, what needs to be done to keep the building from collapsing as a result of removing it.
